# How to fix YT play button which is not clickable on mobile device?

Tags: javascript, iframe, youtube-iframe-api

I have okfocus/okvideo player on one page which plays full-screen video using the Youtube video ID. The video plays fine on desktop, however when I try to view the same on mobile, YT play button is not clickable. If the mobile screen is touched before the video load, the video plays fine.

Can anyone help to resolve this?

```
$(window).bind("load", function(){
  $.okvideo({
      source: 'nKnVebGqyLI',
      volume: 50,
    controls: false,
    captions: false,
    autoplay: true,
    disablekeyControl: true
  });
});
```

Comment: It's a new feature - an active interaction must occur before auto play executes.

Comment: @JackBashford I do understand that, and I am not expecting the video to autoplay on mobile device. The issue I am facing is the YT play button is not clickable, and hence the video dosen't play.